# run cron job every 15 min on putty

Tags: cron

I want cron job to run from 3rd to 5th day of every month from 07:37 AM to 9:00 PM every 15 minutes
: as per my knowledge 37 7-21 3-5 * *

other is daily from 05:05 PM to 06:05 PM every 5 minutes

someone help me

Answer (score 0):

If you write */5 - it lunches each 5 mins, hours, days etc....
If you write 1-5/1 it lanches each 1 ... in interval from one to five

In you case:
5/5 17-18 * * *

At every 5th minute from 5 through 59 past every hour from 17 through 18.

Comment: 5/5 17-18 * * *  ( getting error Non standard! May not work with every cron.) is this correct.. thanks @Vitaly Gorlychev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).